# How can I mock waiting library in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, polling

I'm using the [`waiting`](https://github.com/vmalloc/waiting) library in some of my code to wait for a condition to become true. As a part of the library, `waiting.wait` returns `True` when the predicate is true; otherwise it throws and exception or waits forever depending on timeout values, etc.

I'd like to patch this in my tests to always return `True` without getting into the wait cycle. Here's my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from unittest.mock import Mock
import waiting
from waiting import wait

def test_waiting():
    waiting.wait.return_value = True
    # Below *should* wait forever because it can never be true.
    # Want to make it return true instead.
    return wait(lambda: False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert(test_waiting())
```

What I find, though, is that it actually calls the library's code instead of short-circuiting the return.

How can I force this method to simply return a value (or raise a side-effect) without actually calling the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `waiting.wait.return_value = True` won't work, because `waiting.wait` is not a mock object. You only added an arbitrary attribute to the existing `wait` function, but that function won't use that attribute.

To mock out the `wait` function, just *mock it directly*:

```
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch('__main__.wait'):
    wait.return_value = True
```

There is no need to mock the internals of the `waiting` library, all you want to happen in your code is that any use of the `wait()` callable immediately returns.

Note that I picked the `__main__` module to patch the name `wait()` in, see [*Where to patch*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) in the `unittest.mock` documentation.

Your actual location may differ, and if you used `import waiting` everywhere, then you'd have to use `mock.patch('waiting.wait')`. Otherwise, you generally would apply it the same module you used `from waiting import wait` in.

Comment: Well, that was silly of me. :) Works perfectly. Cheers!